# Peticion Soap desde Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap

Necesito mandar una petición Soap con spring boot, pero me está dando error al enviar. La petición la he probado con postman y está bien formada y el servidor me responde correctamente.
Necesito que las peticiones se lean de un fichero y no tener que crear los objetos java para manejarla, por ello he creado una plantilla aparte. No obstante mi código no funciona ya que el servidor siempre me devuelve un error.

Esta es la petición que tengo que enviar (plantillaPedidos, que efectivamente funciona y el servidor me devuelve una respuesta coherente):

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Header>
      <elem:CABECERA>
            <clave>?</clave>
         </Element>
      </elem:CABECERA>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ctr:ENTRADA>
         <PEDIDO>1231</PEDIDO>
         <IMPORTE>88</IMPORTE>
         <FECHA>12/2/2019</FECHA>
         <CLIENTE>01252</CLIENTE>
      </ctr:ENTRADA>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Y esta la clase que maneja la llamada soap y la que hace la llamada :

```
@Service 
public class pedido implements pedidoint {

    @Value("${plantillaPedidos}")
    private String template_pedido;

    private ReadTemplate rt = new ReadTemplate();


    public void peticion() {
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance(); 
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection(); 

        String soapEndpointUrl = "http://192.168.0.1/030/Procesos/Pedido";
        String request = rt.readTemplate(template_pedido);

        SOAPElement stringToSOAPElement = stringToSOAPElement(request);

        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(); 
        messageFactory.createMessage().setContentDescription(request);

//        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server 
          SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(stringToSOAPElement, "NMC00056M001"), soapEndpointUrl); 

    }

    private SOAPElement stringToSOAPElement(String xmlRequestBody)
            throws SOAPException, SAXException, IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException {

        // Load the XML text into a DOM Document
        final DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                xmlRequestBody.getBytes());
        final org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(stream);

        // Use SAAJ to convert Document to SOAPElement
        // Create SoapMessage
        final MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        final SOAPMessage message = msgFactory.createMessage();
        final SOAPBody soapBody = message.getSOAPBody();

        // This returns the SOAPBodyElement that contains ONLY the Payload
        return soapBody.addDocument((org.w3c.dom.Document) doc);
    }

    private SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(SOAPElement body, String operation)
            throws SOAPException {

        final MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        final SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        final SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        // SOAP Envelope
        final SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        String request = rt.readTemplate(template_pedido);
        // SOAP Body
        envelope.getBody().setTextContent(request);
        final SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        soapBody.setTextContent(request);
        soapBody.addChildElement(body.toString());

        // Mime Headers
        final MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "NMCS");

        soapMessage.setContentDescription(request);
        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        return soapMessage;
    }
}
```